# How change color of selected Excel cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

When I select or use the Find utility, sometimes it's hard to see what it found when there are a lot of colorful things going on in the sheet.

The selection is currently a dark green border, which can be difficult to make out when, for example, a bunch of different rows are colored in the "Good" or other accents (blue, etc).

I would like to be able to change the selection/find color border from dark green to something else.

My current workaround: I'm changing the color of the gridlines on that particular Sheet to pink (While on that sheet, File->Options->Advanced, scroll to "Display options for this worksheet" -> Gridline color).  Pink gridlines at least make it easier to spot the selection, even with the "Good" accents.  Would be nicer if I could just change the selection, though.

Windows 10
Office 2019

Edit: opening it up to possible VB script solutions.

Comment: This needs VBA macro, if you are comfortable with VBA then please [Edit] your post as add TAG 'VBA' to the question!!

Comment: ok, thanks, added vba tag!  Hopefully there's a way to temporarily color the selection border and not permanently change the cell!

Comment: You can always have a look to the [address bar] (http://www.4gaccounts.com/workbook-and-worksheet-in-microsoft-excel-2010/) to check address of active cell. That helps quickly finding it without any extra effort.

Answer (score 1):

*I would like to suggest two VBA macro, first is to apply desire color to the border and second one is set to normal.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 7
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    Target.Borders.ColorIndex = 15
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

- Either press **A**lt+F11 or **R**ight click the Sheet **T**ab to open VB editor.
- **C**opy & **P**aste both VBA code set (as standard module).
- Save the workbook as **M**acro enabled.
- **D**ouble click (1st Macro)applies Pink color to selected cell border.
- **R**ight click (2nd Macro) sets normal (gray) color to selected cell border.

**N.B.**

- ***S***econd Macro is an optional to use.
- *Border colors are editable, you may refer the color list also.*

Comment: This is a good idea and may help someone, so upvoting =)  Just got this VB module added to my sheet, but this not quite what I'm looking for.  What you have there doesn't alter Selection color.   Instead it *permanently* changes the cell borders to Pink on double-click, and *permanently* changes cell borders to Gray on right-click.

Comment: To clarify, this code isn't changing the dark-green "meta" Selection color -- only its targets are changing.

Comment: @icy,, thanks for valuable feedback,, let me say the 1st macro (double click) will apply PINK border to selected cell whether is GREEN or BLUE or Gray and 2nd Macro turn the Border Color to Gray ,, and this is what I found in the question above,,, unable to understand *this code isn't changing the dark-green "meta" Selection color*,, better EDIT your post & upload the Workbook's link on cloud (Drop Box, Imgur or Google drive), so I can find the genuine data !!